# Prestashop:update ps_orders.valid MYSQL

Tags: mysql, prestashop

i'm trying to update the valid value inside ps_orders table from 0 to 1
inside a cycle, but it doesen't change at all, here my code:

//this is the first query:

```
$query = "SELECT ps_orders.reference,ps_orders.id_order,ps_orders.valid,ps_order_detail.product_name,ps_orders.id_order,ps_orders.date_add,ps_orders.payment,ps_order_detail.unit_price_tax_incl,ps_order_detail.id_order_detail,ps_order_detail.product_quantity,ps_order_detail.product_reference,ps_order_detail.product_weight,ps_order_detail.unit_price_tax_incl,ps_address.id_customer,ps_address.firstname,ps_address.lastname,ps_address.address1,ps_address.address2,ps_address.postcode,ps_address.city
    FROM ps_orders
    JOIN ps_order_detail ON  ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order
    JOIN ps_address ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_address.id_customer
    WHERE ps_orders.id_order=$i AND ps_orders.valid=1";
```

//AND THIS IS HOW I WANNA CHANGE THE VALUE

```
$uporder = mysql_query("UPDATE ps_orders SET valid=0 WHERE id=".$row[id_order]);
```

Comment: `$uporder = mysql_query("UPDATE ps_orders SET valid=0 WHERE id=".$row['id_order']);` because you need the field named id_order in the array $row

Comment: in $query i have this:ps_orders.id_order
and array row is a mysql_fetch_array of $query.

it is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no column named `id` in `ps_orders` table, instead use `id_order` column and modify your query like

```
"UPDATE ps_orders SET valid=0 WHERE id_order=".$row[id_order
```